# Maximum Session Lifetime for iPad using PHP?

Tags: php, ios, ipad, cookies, session-variables

I have the following variables set for sessions in my PHP application:

```
ini_set('session.cache_expire',     200000);
ini_set('session.cache_limiter',    'none');
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',  94608000);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',   94608000);
ini_set('session.save_handler',     'user');
ini_set('session.use_cookies',      1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid',    0);
```

When I login via my laptop (Chrome, Safari or Firefox) I am never logged out (at least not for 3 years as set above).  But when I login on my iPad I am logged out every week, and sometimes multiple times per week.

I have tried using debug on my mac, deleting the cookies, inspecting the sessions cookies, etc.  They all have proper expire dates (Feb 2016) but yet I am still logged out.

It seems that the iPad ignores the cookie_lifetime variable.

Anyone run into this problem before?  Any ideas?

Comment: if it wasn't for the fact that it's an ipad, I'd suggest using another browser and seeing if that helps. but since it is, perhaps sacrificing a goat over steve jobs' grave and praying for help might be more productive.

Comment: @MarcB http://www.icab.de/mobile.html someone pointed out that this one is good for configuration :)

Comment: Yeah, problem is that the vast majority of mobile traffic to our site is ipad.  No way around it.  Have to support it, quirks and all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a bug, maybe not. But I have run into the same issue as you. The workaround I used is :

```
session_start(); 
$lifetime = 94608000;
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime);
```

Works for me.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't seem to make any difference.  Still getting logged out on iOS.

Comment: Well, I don't understand… it did solve the issue for me at the time. How long after initiating the session do you get logged out?

Comment: Maybe 2 days? It is very odd, as it happens on both Chrome Android and Safari iOS but not any computer/laptop browser.  I have never been logged out on my laptop or my desktop computer.